# Unable to detect SD card

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, windows

My Raspbian did not boot properly so I have to re-install it, but Windows (XP/7) is not recognizing my SD card. The SD card doesn't show up even in `GParted`, so I cannot use any procedure to re-install Raspbian.

What can I do to detect and format the SD-card for re-installing Raspbian?

Comment: No question has been asked.  Consider revision and clarification.

Comment: it's not your SD card anymore, it's dead SD card. you may get better results if you get another SD card and try with a fresh one.

Comment: No it isn't dead, look at the answer below this

Comment: Thanks for the discussions and the suggestions in this thread. Atleast I could figure out what was the problem with my brand new Pi setup. I have a Pi3 and two days after installation, the SD card was not getting detected. I tried it from two different devices and two different card readers, looks like the brand new Transcend 16 GB Class 10 card had run its course. Used the card from my wife's phone for the time being, and planning to get a new card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is with the SD card, here are some tips:

Is the Lock slider moved from normal position, I have found that this has caused issues before when trying to read via Gparted / ubuntu Disk Manager.

Are you using the same SD card reader, this can cause an issue.

If you are able to get it read remove all partitions and create a Fat 32 Partition and then flash Raspbian or format and put NOOBS on it using the foundations instructions.

If you still can't get anything out of it then the SD card has reached the end of it's life and is dead. Possibly if you have a camera try it in there to format it (Sometimes this has worked for me).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried another sd-card reader/pc and I was able to format the sd!

Answer (score 0):

Please open Windows Disk Partition and delete the Volume, then re-format it. It will start showing up in My Computer.

Comment: Doing what you suggest is impossible when the SD card is not detected.